# Grunt with babel and browserify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a simple JavaScript project that uses Babel to transpile ECMAScript 6 to ES5 and then needs Browserify to take advantage of ES6's Modules.

As so, I came up with this `Gruntfile.js` to compile it:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  "use strict";

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

  grunt.initConfig({
    "babel": {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          "lib/pentagine.js": "lib/pentagine_babel.js",
          "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState.js": "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState_babel.js"
        }
      }
    },

    "browserify": {
      dist: {
        files: {
          "lib/pentagine.js": "lib/pentagine_babel.js",
          "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState.js": "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState_babel.js"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("default", ["babel", "browserify"]);
};
```

`grunt` runs just fine without any errors. However, I get the following errors:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` on `export`
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` on `import`

Basically what I'm doing in the main file is the following:

```
export class Game {
    ...
}
```

And then importing it like:

```
import {Sprite, Game} from "lib/pentagine";
```

I'm doing all the code according to ECMAScript 6. However, the export/import does not seem to be working and is instead colliding with JavaScript reserved words (despite me having `browserify.js` working).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't you `browserify` the files created after the `babel` task? Note that the property name is the destination file and the value after the `:` is the source file. (I assume that your ES6 files are called `filename.js` instead of `filename_babel.js`)

```
files: {
   "destination_file": "src_file"
}
```

Which leads to:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    "babel": {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          "lib/pentagine_babel.js": "lib/pentagine.js",
          "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState_babel.js": "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState.js"
        }
      }
    },

    "browserify": {
      dist: {
        files: {
          "lib/pentagine_browserified.js": "lib/pentagine_babel.js",
          "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState_browserified.js": "demos/helicopter_game/PlayState_babel.js"
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

or just `lib/pentagine_babel.js": "lib/pentagine_babel.js"` to `browserify` the same file.